# Doctrine bidirectional association error. Memory exhausted

Tags: doctrine-orm, zend-framework3

I have two doctrine  entities *school* and *schoolLocation* in zend framwork

*school entity*

```
/**
 * @var schoolLocation
 * 
 * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="\School\Entity\SchoolLocation", mappedBy="school", cascade={"persist","remove"})
 * 
 */
protected $schoolLocation;
```

and

*schoolLocation entity*

```
/**
 * @var school
 *
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="\School\Entity\School", inversedBy="schoolLocation")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="school_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
protected $school;
```

I've shown bidirectional association. Now whenever I try to get school_location

`$schoolLocation = $this->entityManager->getRepository(SchoolLocation::class)->findAll();`

and `print_r($schoolLocation)` I am getting following error message:

`Fatal error:  Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 65015808 bytes) in F:\projects\test\module\School\src\Service\SchoolManager.php on line 190`

Could anybody please help me telling, what am I doing wrong here ?

Comment: How large is result set for your query?

Comment: one row in both tables

Comment: Is this error keeps showing up in a case if there is no `print_r` is used? Also what is on line 190 of `SchoolManager.php`?

Comment: @Flying line 190 is 'print_r($schoolLocation);' I am checking if what will happen if there is no print_r

Comment: You should use the Doctrine CLI tools to verify your code. This would've shown up with `./vendor/bin/doctrine-module orm:validate-schema` (modify path of first bit to your doctrine-module in bin)

Comment: Thanks for the input @rkeet 
I will check today.

Answer (score 2):

When you use print_r on an object with a circular relation it will keep printing the relation, untill you run out of memory.

```
class A {
    public $name = "class a";

    public $b;

    public function __construct(B $b) {
        $this->b = $b;
    }
}

class B {
    public $name = "class b";

    public $a;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->a = new A($this);
    }
}

print_r(new B);
```

This code demonstrates what is happening. The amount of recusrion shown, depends on your PHP configuration.

I recommend using [Xdebug](https://xdebug.org/) instead of printing, this has many advantages. In your case it will allow you to easily inspect the circular relation.